# Java Service Wrapper exception stack trace is split into multiple log events

Tags: java, logging, log4j2, logback, java-service-wrapper

We have one J2EE service deployed as service using JSW (Tanuki Software). Here is my logging configuration

```
wrapper.console.format=LPTM
wrapper.console.loglevel=INFO
wrapper.console.flush=TRUE
```

When ever we log exception stack traces, they are being split into multiple log events which is very annoying to debug. Log looks as follows

Simple log statement

`log.error("error happened during authorization check", e)`

**e** represents exception in above log

```
INFO   | jvm 2    | 2023/07/01 12:09:46 | Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
INFO   | jvm 2    | 2023/07/01 12:09:46 |   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
INFO   | jvm 2    | 2023/07/01 12:09:46 |   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
INFO   | jvm 2    | 2023/07/01 12:09:46 |   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
INFO   | jvm 2    | 2023/07/01 12:09:46 |   at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
```

I tried with JUL, Log4j2, Logback and the issue remains. I think it is issue with wrapper itself.

Has anyone ever faced it?
Is there a config or setting that can stop splitting the exception stack trace into multiple lines.

Thanks